# How to insert email ID field with @ from a stored procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, email, stored-procedures, insert

I am having a basic mysql stored procedure for inserting user data along with email id.
For example

```
CALL INSERTUSER(
'Someone',
'someone@email.com'
);
```

My problem is that the stored procedure is taking @ as special character.I am new to mysql.
How can I insert this? Is there any escape character?Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CALL INSERTUSER(
'Someone',
'someone\@email.com'
);
```